# Animating two UIView subviews at the same time does not work

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, core-animation

For some reason i am not able two animate two subviews postion. I have wrote the following

```
[self addChildViewController:self.photosViewController];
[self.photosViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -self.view.frame.size.height,    self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

[self.view addSubview:self.photosViewController.view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{

                         [self.stepsView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
                         [self.photosViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {

                             button.tag = 0;
                         }
                     }];
```

`self.stepsView` is an `IBOutlet` `UIView` and `self.photosViewController.view` is an child view controllers view that has been added to the view.

With the current code only the `self.PhotosViewController.view` animates. However if i comment out the line where i add the child view controllers view as a `subview` then the `self.stepsView` animates correctly.

Even if i add the child view controller and its view before this method is called the same error happens.

Need help as i ran in to this a couple of months back with another app and had to do a dirty hack to get around it and now want to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Is self.stepsView non-nil when that animation block is called?

Comment: why are you calling both addChildViewController and addSubView?

Comment: @jsd Its in IB and i never remove it from the view so is never nil

Comment: @sixthcent Because from my understanding of the apple docs and vids they say that should always add the viewcontroller of the view that you want to add as a subview as a child view controller of the View Controller you are adding too... if that makes sense.

Comment: My comment was prompted by your statement that the view animates if you comment out the addSubview part. It looks like you may have to do two separate animations one followed by another. If you hide stepsView  in the first animation and then start the animation to show photosView in the completion handler, you may be able to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the section on view animation in the [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH1-SW2) there is a [specific mention](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW25) of how to animate subviews.

Basically, you should use `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` rather than `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late reply thought i have marked this answer

Answer (score 0):

The first view will not be visible, because its origin.y is beyond the height of the visible view. If it was not visible when the animation starts, you will of course see nothing.

The second view is changed to fill the screen. Again, what you see depends on its initial position.

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned. I have intentially of set the photosViewController to be above the view. the point of the animation is to animate the self.stepsView down of the screen while at the same time animate the self.PhotosViewController.View onto the screen from the top if that makes sense. 

Also note that the both animations do work. Just not together. If i add the self.PhotosViewController.view as a subview then the self.stepsView will not animate at all, just stays still while the other one animates.

Comment: Does one of the views have a non identity `transform`? If so, you cannot animate the frame but should use center instead.

Comment: Also, it might have to do with the relative position of the views. Try `insertSubview:atIndex:0` instead of `insertSubview:`.